# maven archetype copy shell script having its own variable

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I am trying to create project structure  by using archetype as below.

```
mvn archetype:generate  
    -DarchetypeGroupId=com.td.abc.myplatform 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=my-custom-archetype 
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
    -DgroupId=com.abc.myplatform.muntjac
    -DartifactId=muntjac 
    -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
    -DappName=muntjac
```

The archetype also copies some of the shell script which is having few lines as below.

> > my-shell.sh (part of my-shell.sh)

```
Line#1 RPM_PACKAGE_NAME="${appName}"
Line#2 RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION="1.0.0"
Line#3 RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE="1"
Line#4 REVISION_VERSION="${BUILD_NUMBER}_${BUILD_VCS_NUMBER:0:8}"
```

However the archetype generation fails due to my shell script variable `${BUILD_VCS_NUMBER:0:8}` by saying syntax error expected { or ( instead of :

Is there anyway I can make this work without modifying my shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make it work without modifying your script.
I replaced every $ character in resource files with ${dollar}.
And added this on top of pom.xml: #set($dollar = '$')